# std::promise to notify multiple clients

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

I have an API that has to return a future result (future/shared_future) to clients. There are cases where I know I can return "the same future" object multiple times because I have an associated std::promise that can/should deliver the result to multiple clients(pseudocode).

```
std::future<int> getVal()
{
   //I have a list of promises kept
   if (promiseExists)
   {
     //this throws an exception because get_future() can be called only one time, unfortunately
     return existingPromise.get_future();
   }
   ....
}
```

The problem is that you cannot call get_future() multiple times on the same instance, or obtain somehow a shared_future object from same promise.

There is a workaround for getVal to return a shared_future (obtained from constructing shared_future from existingPromise.get_future()) but in this case I have to cache shared_future object with the promise object, and it would be simpler on just having a promise object on which somehow to be able to return future multiple times to different clients. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Why do you need to keep the promise around?  Only the provider of the result needs the promise, all the consumers of the result only need the (shared) future.

Comment: I have an api that uses callbacks so I have to keep the promise myself so that I can set the result when that api finishes